# "Footsteps Sounds" or "Footstep Sounds"

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

I have a friend who wants to title his thesis "Footsteps Sounds".
I don't think this sounds right but I can't explain why. To me it should be "Footstep Sounds".

Are both correct with different meanings? If not, why is one wrong and the the other right?

Comment: Unless he’s a foley artist I’m having trouble envisioning a thesis entitled “Footstep sounds”

Comment: Would you use *icecreams flavors* or *icecream flavors*?

Comment: @Davo I would use ice cream flavours... But I still can't explain why the other is wrong

Comment: both are plural, which is incorrect. "Footstep Sounds" would be more grammatically correct. However, not sure of your meaning, but "footsteps" also implies the sounds of a footstep if you use the verb associating with sound, such as "hearing footsteps".

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is "Footstep Sounds." The sentence can not have a double positive.

Comment: What's a double positive? Why can't it have one, whatever it is? Do you mean that plural nouns cannot be used attributively on other plural nouns?